# Creating a simple addition calculation but error when compiling [Assembly Code]

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I am currently learning assembler language. It not easy and I am still learning but I wanted to create a simple addition calculation by getting the value from the user but I couldn't even get the compiler to run my code it keeps on saying
`illegal command:`

[image]
File name is **USERSUM.ASM**

I am using the **DOSbox** to write mine assembler code using the **TASM file**

```
title Calculate 2 Sum
; This program is to calculate the sum input from the user

.model small
.stack 100h

.data
input1 db 0ah, odh, "Input 1st Number: ", "$"
input2 db 0ah, odh, "Input 2nd Number: ", "$"
output db 0ah, odh, "The sum is: ", "$"

number 1 dw ?
number 2 dw ?
result dw ?

.code
main  proc

      MOV ax, @data
      MOV ds,ax

;Print 1st Message Input
      MOV ah, 9
      MOV dx,offset input1
      int 21h

      MOV ah, 1
      int 21h
      MOV bl, al

;Print 2nd Message Input
      MOV ah, 9
      MOV dx,offset input2
      int 21h

      MOV ah, 1
      int 21h
      MOV bh, al

;addition
      SUB number1,'0'
      SUB number2,'0'

      MOV ax, number1
      add ax, number2

      MOV result, ax
      add result,'0'

;Print Output 
      MOV ah, 9
      MOV dx,offset output
      int 21h

      MOV ah, 2
      MOV dl, bh
      int 21h

      MOV ax, 4C00h
      int 21h

main  endp
end   main
```

**I want my output to be like this:-**

```
Input 1st Number: 2
Input 2nd Number: 4
The sum is: 6
```

I can't figure out the problem. Am I missing something in the code or did I forget to put something important in? Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: The assembler usually tells you which line has the error. Or there may be something wrong with the way you run it, but you did not show that. PS: you never actually store your inputs into the `number` variables.

Comment: I would put it in but then there no errors on the code. It only has an error when I try to run it.

Comment: @Jester I didn't store input into `number` how do I do that?

Comment: Instead of `mov`ing them from `al` into `bl` and `bh`, `mov` the into `number1` and `number2`.   
 The input character is in `al`.  Suggest to clear `ah`, to create a 16-bit number in `ax`, then `mov number1, ax`.  Remove the space in the declarations of `number1` and `number2`: the space that is between the word numbers and the numeral.

Comment: ok let me give it a try

Comment: but i still can't run @ErikEidt

Comment: I paste the error run compiler image

Comment: What command(s) did you run to assemble your .asm file into a .com file?

Comment: I type in command run usersum. but no I didn't run .asm file to .com file. It stays as .asm file no changes @NateEldredge

Comment: That will not work, then.  .asm files can't be run directly.  You need to use an assembler to generate a .com file.  That's what tasm is for.

Comment: I didn't know that interesting. How do I generate .asm to .com file

Comment: @NateEldredge I know how to generate hehe but I still can't get the output right. It doesn't show number instead picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the register `dl` is a **byte** but your variable`result` is defined as a **word** by `dw` ,so the assembler says `operand is not same`

just use the `ptr` operator to change the type of `result` to **byte** like this

```
MOV dl, byte ptr result
```

or just use `dx`

```
mov dx,result
```

this is my code modified from the code in  your answer,note it is `0dh` instead of `odh`

```
.model small
.stack 100h
    
.data
input1 db 0ah, 0dh, "Input 1st Number: ", "$";NOTE here and the next 2 lines is 0dh instead of odh
input2 db 0ah, 0dh, "Input 2nd Number: ", "$"
output db 0ah, 0dh, "The sum is: ", "$"

number1 dw ?
number2 dw ?
result dw ?

.code
main  proc

      MOV ax, @data
      MOV ds,ax

;Print 1st Message Input
      MOV ah, 9
      MOV dx,offset input1
      int 21h

      MOV ah, 1
      int 21h
      MOV number1, ax

;Print 2nd Message Input
      MOV ah, 9
      MOV dx,offset input2
      int 21h

      MOV ah, 1
      int 21h
      MOV number2, ax

;addition
      SUB number1,'0'
      SUB number2,'0'

      MOV ax, number1
      add ax, number2

      MOV result, ax
      add result,'0'

;Print Output
      MOV ah, 9
      MOV dx,offset output
      int 21h

      MOV ah, 2
      MOV dx,  result;or use mov dl,byte ptr result
      int 21h

      MOV ax, 4C00h
      int 21h

main  endp
end   main
```

[output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bioJ8.png)